# Simple question on using constructers and methods in java and why the constructor isn't working

Tags: java, constructor, getter

I am just starting to learn OOP, constructers and class methods. My problem is that when my constructer is called and the value given it doesn't work. An object will be created but the value it is created with doesn't seem to work or 'apply'. Maybe the code will explain it better. My circle class is this:

```
public class MyCircle {
    double radius;
    
    public MyCircle() {
        
    }
    public MyCircle(double radius) {
        

    }
    
    final double pi = 3.14159;
    public double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }
    
    public double getCircumference() {
        return radius*pi;
    }
    
    public double getArea() {
        return radius*radius*pi;
    }
    
}
```

It seems ok to me but when i try to use it from a testing class like this:

```
public class MyCircleTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double radius = 26.5;
    MyCircle myCoolCircle = new MyCircle(radius);
    System.out.println("Circumference of myCoolCircle: " + myCoolCircle.getCircumference() );
    System.out.println("Area of myCoolCircle: " + myCoolCircle.getArea());
```

The output reads:
Circumference of myCoolCircle: 0.0
Area of myCoolCircle: 0.0
Its like it isn't constructing properly and i dont know why.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: in `public MyCircle(double radius) {} `you have to explicitly write what to do with the `radius` argument. Your program can't figure it out by itself

Comment: Some languages have shortcuts for assigning constructor parameters to fields. Java is not one of those languages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A constructor is just a method, really. It's not voodoo magic; methods have parameters. Parameters aren't particularly useful unless you actually use them. There is absolutely no link whatsoever between your field (named `radius`) and the parameter of your constructor (also named `radius`).

If you want the action of the constructor to be: "Take the value of this parameter, and assign it to the radius field", then you'd have to write that:

```
public MyCircle(double radius) {
    this.radius = radius;
}
```

Note that we have to use `this.radius` to refer to the field, as the param name `radius` 'shadows' (makes it otherwise impossible to access) the field which is also named `radius`. Nevertheless, this is idiomatic java.

Comment: Great answer. well explained that they need to be linked

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you are not assigning the passed value of `radius` to the constructor parameter. Java does not assign the variable to the constructor parameter itself.
Try assigning it like doing `this` keyword.

```
public MyCircle(double radius) {
    this.radius = radius;
}
```

Comment: Great answers. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
public MyCircle(double radius) {
   this.radius = radius
}
```

Comment: I was not the downvoter, but if I may offer an explanation as to why this *might* have been downvoted, "*use this*" is not very helpful for a beginner, because it does not explain *why* their attempt was unsuccessful. See [Reinier's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63153460/1898563) for an example of the same answer written in a more beginner-friendly way

Comment: Great answers. Thanks everyone

Comment: @Michael I think beginner got the answer. Even i appreciate your comment.

Comment: @Mike if you got your answer please upvote and accept my answer. Thanks